# How to get the localized folder names with Java?

Tags: java, file, internationalization, system

I want the localized folder name of "C:/Program Files". For example "C:/Programme" in German. How can I do this with Java?

Comment: you don't need to translate the foldernames, "C:\Program Files" will work on German systems as well, "C:\Programme" just links to "C:\Program Files".

Comment: It is for displaying in the user interface.

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html

Comment: The only method that work is Files.isSameFile(). This help a little.

Comment: I guess you want to create your own file explorer, or something like that. I assume you'll be translating UI anyway, so I guess the best option is to leave the task to translators. I don't think Java has such API, sorry. Other options include reading it out of registry key or calling Windows API, both of which are not necessary safe.